# How can I change file permissions so only a certain program can access it?

Tags: c#, file-permissions

I am using C# to make a program which requires a password, and those passwords would be saved in a file. The problem is, I want the program to have access to the file, but not the user. How exactly can I do that? (With GUI, DOS or C#)

Comment: maybe this will help you...http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15392/Implementing-Protected-Configuration-With-Windows

Comment: You are working *against* and not *with* the security system. The .NET security system is built to protect *trustworthy users* from *hostile programs*, not to protect the secrets of trustworthy programs from hostile users! Your scenario doesn't make any sense: programs act *on behalf of users* so it doesn't make sense to say that there is a program that can do something a user cannot. You are on an impossible errand, so abandon it and start over by building a security system that trusts the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm..  the bottom-line answer here is that there is no way that you can prevent a determined ***and skilled*** user from accessing the data - the only thing you can do is make it difficult for him/her.

Here are some possible strategies you might consider for this:  Each of these methods requires a different level of skill for the user to obtain the data.  The first is almost certainly the hardest to crack.

1. Encrypt the file - use the .NET [ProtectedData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx) class
2. As in [dasblinkenlight's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17513136/50356), create the file under a different user account
3. Use [Protected Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa939852(v=winembedded.5).aspx)

Comment: AFAIK, `ProtectedData` encrypts the data based on the user credentials, so it would be trivial for the same user to access the data. And I think the other options have the exact same problem.

Comment: There is one problem...I compiled and used the example file from the link for `ProtectedData`, and ran it twice. They came up with diffrent encryptions for the same characters. If I save it to a file and run the program a different time, will the Unpropect function work the same way as when it was protected in a different execution?

Comment: @Monkeyman: you ask the question, but it sounds like you didn't test it!  Just test it!  (Chances are, each encryption used different initialization vectors, so you would expect that it would generate different encrypted data.)

Comment: @svick: Hence the first sentence in my answer, but it depends on who the user is.  I'm pretty sure my grandmother couldn't get to the data.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with this approach is that the password file is stored locally. No matter where you put it, if the legitimate program can read it, any user running with the same permissions can get it too. All you can do is to try to hide it, but that will only give you security though obscurity.

For normal desktop applications that store credentials locally, you should use a **hash** function on the password given, store that hash, and when authenticating users again, hash their input and compare hashes instead. **Never encrypt user passwords, never store passwords as plain text**.

In case some "curious" users peek at that file, all they have would be a hash that they have to crack to make any value of it. A determined user will always be able to do that, given enough time, but normally most people are scared at it.

Answer (score -2):

You can create a crypto algorithm so other programs can't open it.

Comment: This is nonsense. If the user can run a program that decrypts the message then other programs can run that program too.